# Pandas - split dataframe based on complex rule

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to clean data coming from a time series. When data was missing, it was filled with the last recorded value but this does not suit my project.

I can accept at most two consecutive equal value, otherwise I assume that data is not coming from the original source, so I delete it. The problem I am facing is that I need to represent the missing data with a "hole".

Let's do an example: my serie is [1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 1]. What i want to get is [[1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6], [7, 4, 5, 5, 1]]. (of course, for every element I also have the timestamp, I omit it for the sake of simplicity).

```
def removeAnomalies(hist):
  nextNotEqual = hist.ne(hist.shift(1))
  nextEqual = hist.eq(hist.shift(1))
  nextNextNotEqual = hist.ne(hist.shift(2))
  filtered =  hist.loc[nextNotEqual | (nextEqual & nextNextNotEqual)]

  return filtered
```

With this code, I have achieved the "filtering" part of the problem, but I don't know how to split the dataframe in order to have two different data frames.

Comment: what should be the result for this input `[1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 1]` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest [[1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6], [7, 4, 5, 5, 1]]. In the case the end of the sequence is 5, 5, 5, 1 and not 5, 5, 1 I expect a third slice with only a "1"

Comment: *of course, for every element I also have the timestamp* - do you need to keep datetime index for all resulting chunks ?

Comment: No, it is not important, but I have it if it may be useful to achieve the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean mask `m2` to flag the rows having more than two consecutive previous same values. Use this mask to filter the valid rows (`hist[~m2]`) then group the filtered series by the different blocks (`m2.cumsum()`) where the start of each blocks is identified by the different set of consecutive True values in boolean mask `m2`

```
m1 = hist != hist.shift()
m2 = hist.groupby(m1.cumsum()).cumcount() >= 2

[[*g] for _, g in hist[~m2].groupby(m2.cumsum())]
```

---

```
# input [1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 1]
# output: [[1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6], [7, 4, 5, 5, 1]]

# input: [1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1]
# output: [[1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6], [7, 4, 5, 5], [1]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also better than what I needed because I can parametrize the number of allowed consecutive repetition